# How to delete data by force using djnago orm?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-orm

I have multiple table connected to each other and one table that is connect to that network. Now I want to delete the first table and all the data related to that foreign key.

Answer (score 2):

You can specify `on_delete` arg in ForeighKey model and it will do what you specify when the row is deleted.

More details in [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey)

```
my_field = models.ForeignKey(
    'User',
    on_delete=models.CASCADE,
)
```

Comment: It already specified in the table but still it shows the error of the foreign key.